# c++ std::exception ... may I have more please?

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, fstream

I have browsed http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception & http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream looking for I/O exceptions I could possibly throw.  I know I can create a custom exception class and there are plenty of websites offering example code, but I would like some guidance specifically on best practices.

Also, is there a library I ought to concentrate on using to make my life easier?

Comment: Maybe you can explain what this java like utility does for those of us who are not familiar with it?

Comment: Not being familiar with Java, I'm not quite getting this question. What is it that an exception is supposed to do, except get you out of the main flow? Different exception types give you the ability to choose which ones you catch and which ones propagate, but you don't need fine grained classes for that.

Comment: I edited the question to provide clarification.  I have felt as if c++ was simply lacking in the exception department and that their exceptions are dated ... the c++ committee needs to get on this in my opinion.  Perhaps fine-grained classes aren't necessary but, realizing the inevitable, I am dissatisfied with what c++ offers and looking for advice on best practice to create my own.

Comment: @user633658 No offence, but from what position of experience are you taking this view? The committee is open to suggestions, though I don't feel qualified to make any yet. There has to be good reasons for the committee to include something in the `std` library.

Comment: Judging from your question and comments, it sounds more like a rant than a question. Sure the library could have more exceptions; better? What are you stuck on and how can we help? You already know you need to create a custom exception class, do you need help doing that? If so, ditch the subtext on wishing you didn't have to.

Comment: @juanchopanza Take a look at the Java exception library. That is what I am referring to and not something nebulous.

Comment: @GManNickG Need help? check! stuck? check! Need help writing best practice exception class? check! That is also obvious from the question too for those that carefully read.  Need help doing this? check! Also in the question.  Ditch subtext? Call it what you will but this is not a rant and simply an observation as java programmer.

Comment: @user633658 Calm down. I think you have annoyed a lot of people; you appear to be new to the language and relatively new to the site, yet you have just told us that we have all been doing it wrong for years. *What are the std::exception best practices?* would have probably been a much better question.

Comment: @Alex Chamberlain I have less than one year of experience as a hired c++ programmer and my only paid experience as a Java programmer was during an internship as required for graduation.  I do not stand on anything but my God given ability to stand, think rationally, and be a human. Thus, as a human, I am dissatisfied with the c++ exception class but not allowing this to keep me from enjoying programming in c++. Also, as one human to another, it is my suggestion not to put emphasis on stature; respect but don't worship!

Comment: @Alex Chamberlain Alex, you clicked the link to my question, took exception to my question, and proceeded to question my stature and presume I have offended all those with greater stature.  If this is true for you, then so be it.  If you do not like my question and choose not to answer it, then hit the back button.  Simple as that.  I am on this site to get help.  If you don't want to help, hit the back button.  This could all be avoided.

Comment: @user633658 - please describe the specific facilities you're trying to replicate. It's very hard to tell what you need otherwise.

Comment: @Useless I am not trying to replicate any facility but, as my question asks, " I know I can create a custom exception class and there are plenty of websites offering example code, but I would like some guidance specifically on best practices." & "is there a library (although I dislike employing libraries - learn nothing) you folks have used before (prob one in boost perhaps?) that I ought to concentrate on using to make my life easier?"  Anything else in that question is simply my own opinion which has apparently made some children angry.  Also, I am about to designate an answer.

Comment: So you just want to know how to write your own exception classes in good style? Sorry, it sounded like you wanted to reproduce some (unspecified) aspect of the "java like utility" you mentioned.

Comment: @Useless I agree I could have just asked my question but I chose to frame it in an aspect of my experience.  Also, this: "The c++ committee has introduced some new exceptions within std::exception but I am curious why have they not endeavored to provide java like utility?" is a question not seeking "to reproduce some (unspecified) aspect of the \"java like utility\" you mentioned".  I fail to reason how you arrived at such a conclusion.

Comment: You didn't say what the "java like utility" provided, or why you wanted that. The obvious interpretation is that you wanted it only because it's more familiar to you. If you described what functionality you wanted, it would be possible to address constructively.

Comment: @Useless "...to provide java like utility" means well-encapsulated exception behavior which c++ sorely lacks.  What does that mean?  I can use a class in c++ called IOException and write a try/catch/finally block that uses such a class without the need to write a custom exception class myself. FYI, IOException is a class in the Java package java.io.IOException.  I enjoy programming in c++ but, as an OOP language, it still leaves some things to be desired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++11 introduces the new header [system_error](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/system_error) for low level errors. It is possible to write your own error categories.

This might be good starting point for writing your own error handling in modern C++.

Comment: I like this and will look into it for making custom exception class.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer to mention `system_error`, which is the proper solution in this case IMO.

Comment: @ildjarn This was going to be the answer because he is introducing a c++11 solution and I like doing new things.  If I get more recommendations, I will happily switch the designation to this answer.

Comment: @user633658 : Boost.Exception is an equally appropriate answer if used in conjunction with [Boost.System](http://www.boost.org/libs/system/), and has the added advantage of working with C++03.

Comment: @ildjarn Then please help me designate the most appropriate answer the community believes represents best practice which what I am after. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_category is something I was looking for.

Comment: @user633658 : I've voted on the existing answers, there's not much more I can do. ;-]

Comment: I chose this as the answer because it not only represents a language implementation but also new for c++.  I chose not to represent the boost answer because boost is an external library and not everyone will use boost but everyone should be programming to the latest c++ standard.  Of course, all answers given represent very intelligent choices to make when implementing a custom exception class or using a very good library.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of [predefined exceptions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception), but generally, you either define your own or throw `std::runtime_error` as a first approximation.

Generally, you would extend `std::runtime_error`, or another derivative of `std::exception` that is more appropriate.

For example,

```
class io_error : public std::runtime_error {
public:
    using std::runtime_error::runtime_error;
};
```

Comment: Good idea, I like that.  I do disagree that the exception library contains "alot" because I see some exceptions lacking and the ones present could simple be revised as some appear to be unnecessary.

Comment: @user633658 Which ones are unnecessary? I think they're all used in the `std` library somewhere.

Comment: Such as logic-error which appears to be not as useful for example.  As I wrote, Java is beautiful when it comes to exceptions.  Maybe because they simply improved upon a good idea that c++ started and I think c++ could follow suit with some revision of their own.

Comment: @user633658 `std::logic_error` is incredibly useful. It should be thrown when algorithmic invariants are not met, such as `std::invalid_argument`. They could also be used within development time assertions. `std::out_of_range` is thrown by `std::vector::at`; a similar exception must be thrown in Java, as I understand it always checks for range errors?

Comment: @user633658 "Java is beautiful when it comes to exceptions" no, exceptions in Java are terrible.

Comment: @Alex Chamberlain I agree with you and thank you for demonstrating examples of this.  I simply would like to see more encapsulated behavior and less dependence upon writing custom classes.  I enjoy programming in c++ but do think some aspects could be updated.  Also, thank you for beautifully tying present std::exceptions to real-world examples.  This is certainly not done in my textbook from which I draw my knowledge of c++.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the libraries part of the question, have [a look](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/exception/doc/boost-exception.html) at `boost::exception`.

Boost exceptions can move from thread to thread, and you can dynamically attach information to the exception - with `operator<<` - as you catch (and optionally rethrow) it. Also, the `BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION` macro records the file, line and function name in your expression for pretty printing.

Otherwise, it's common practice to define your own exceptions for your project. But it's difficult to give more specific answers since I'm not familiar with the "java like utility" you are talking about.

As a more general note, one of C++ design principle is to do what you ask and nothing more, which is in some case a blessing and in some cases means more work - and is quite different from java. The primary goal of exceptions is to interrupt normal program flow with `throw`/`catch`, and C++ does just that.

If you just want a simple string message:

```
struct E: std::exception {
  const char* msg;
  E(const char* msg_): msg(msg_) {}
  const char* what() const { return msg; }
};
// ...
throw E("invalid operation name");
```

Comment: Java was referenced because of their well-contained exception library.  Agreed that c++ handles exceptions but their exception library is sorely lacking and I really don't want to have to write a custom class to handle exceptions.

Comment: @user Neither your question nor your comment explain clearly in what ways you find C++ exceptions to be incomplete.

Comment: Depending on the point of view: C++ has a less complete library than java - or it doesn't force its library design on you. That's a fact, and it's arguably a feature. Use boost::exception or other libraries if you like. Also, writing a simple exception class with an error string would take less characters than this comment.

Comment: @us2012 This is question about writing c++ exception classes.  I preambled my question with a comment and did not expect this discussion to degenerate into emotions.  To answer your question, I think c++ exceptions such as logic_error are dated and the c++ committee could revise it by adding more especially in the area of i/o.  I do not want to examine the state of an fstream object. No, I just want to know if an exception occurs and to handle it in a Java-esque fashion.  In some ways I feel c++ could make exceptions far more object oriented.

Comment: @Antoine I like your reasoned sensibility on that comment.

Comment: @user633658: my intent was not to offend you. Sorry I went a little strong-;) I feel you are asking why C++ is not java, but thinking like that will only lead to frustration. Some aspects of C++ are dated because of complexity and backward-compatibility; its design principles are different from java. Both languages have strength, but if you work in C++ don't think in java. For instance, it is not always necessary to have one class per exception type, since the error type may be conveyed by other means (arbitrary data in boost::exception).

Comment: @Antoine No, I am not asking why isn't c++ Java. Virtual Machines only get one so far and c/c++ are beautiful languages I enjoy programming in.  I was expressing frustration in my question that c++ is not growing as an OOP language fast enough.  In many areas, I still feel like I am programming in C. I do agree with you in principle and I am very happy boost has come along.